# Can I apply a PHP session to a page request made with cURL?

Tags: php, curl

I want to read data from a website with cURL but from a certain user logged in with a session. I don't know cURL but I'll be reading the documentation on php.net tonight.

Can this be done? I don't have access to the database on the server but I have a php script on it, so I want to get the username of the user that is logged in.

Comment: Ask the question again _after_ you've read the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [curl_setopt()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) coupled with the `CURLOPT_COOKIE` option to set the `PHPSESSID` cookie:

```
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'PHPSESSID=' . $usersSessionId);
```

Optionally, if your server allows `PHPSESSID` to be passed as a `GET` parameter in the URL, you could just append `PHPSESSID=123456` to the URL and not bother with a cookie.

Comment: Thanks! This actually helped not as other people have replied here...